# plt.imshow() display the image inside another image

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

I am new to Python and I apologize if this is very basic. I am doing image processing but when I read a png image using cv2 and then display the image using plt.imshow() it gives me strange images(Image with extra boundries). I did the following.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('img.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
plt.imshow(img1, 'gray')
plt.title("ORIGINAL")
plt.savefig("original.png")

  
kernel = np.ones((4,4),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(img1, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
plt.imshow(opening, 'gray')
plt.title("OPENING OF ORIGINAL")
plt.savefig("opening of original.png")
```

I am attaching the resulting images here.

[the original image]

[image: 1]

[After displaying the image through plt.imshow().]

[image: 2]

[after doing opening image processing technique]

[image: 3]

Comment: please post the image file itself, not a plot or screenshot of it. please clarify the issue *in your question* ([edit] your question). you use `plt.savefig` instead of `cv.imwrite`. is that the source of your issues?

Comment: @Mazhar, if you tried `plt.axis("off")` before saving the image what do you get?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, thank you for replying.  plt.savefig is not the issue, even if I don't save the figure and just display it using plt.imshow() it still gives me the extra frame.

Comment: @Bilal, thank you for replying, plt.axis("off") remove the extra frame but the extra white area is still in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the extra part you're talking about a red area？[image]

If I understand correctly, This code can be used to cut the transparent part of the picture

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def cv2_crop(im, box):
    return im.copy()[box[1]:box[3], box[0]:box[2], :]

def get_transparency_location(image):
    height, width, channel = image.shape  
    assert channel == 4  
    first_location = None  
    last_location = None  
    first_transparency = []  
    last_transparency = []  
    for y, rows in enumerate(image):
        for x, BGRA in enumerate(rows):
            alpha = BGRA[3]
            if alpha != 0:
                if not first_location or first_location[1] != y:  
                    first_location = (x, y)  
                    first_transparency.append(first_location)
                last_location = (x, y)  
        if last_location:
            last_transparency.append(last_location)

    top = first_transparency[0]
    bottom = first_transparency[-1]
    left = None
    right = None
    for first, last in zip(first_transparency, last_transparency):
        if not left:
            left = first
        if not right:
            right = last
        if first[0] < left[0]:
            left = first
        if last[0] > right[0]:
            right = last

    upper_left = (left[0], top[1])  
    bottom_right = (right[0], bottom[1])  
    box =upper_left[0], upper_left[1], bottom_right[0], bottom_right[1]
    result = cv2_crop(image, box)
    #cv2.imwrite('result.png', result)
    return result
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #img1 = cv2.imread('img.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    image = cv2.imread('img.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)  
    img1 = get_transparency_location(image)

    plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
    plt.imshow(img1, 'gray')
    plt.title("ORIGINAL")
    plt.savefig("original.png")


    kernel = np.ones((4,4),np.uint8)
    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(img1, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
    plt.imshow(opening, 'gray')
    plt.title("OPENING OF ORIGINAL")
    plt.savefig("opening of original.png")
```

[image: newpic1]
[image: newpic2]

Comment: I am talking about the extra boundaries in the images. If you look at the images with the titles "ORIGINAL" and "OPENING OF ORIGINAL" they have extra boundaries. How can I remove these boundaries and display the image without these boundaries like the first image? Thank you!

Comment: yang jiang , Yes the red area. and Yes I can cut them manually but I have thousands of pictures for deep learning model so i cannot deal with them one by one.

Comment: I added the code to delete the transparent part of the picture. I hope it can be helpful to you

Comment: please don't post screenshots of text/code. please explain your code at a high level. comments in chinese will be of no use to the majority of people on this site.

Comment: The transparent part of the picture can be called a, and the non transparent part can be called B. The code distinguishes the transparent part (a) by detecting the pixel value in the picture, and obtains the coordinates of the four corners of the non transparent part (b). After that, the coordinates of the four points are returned. After saving, this effect is realized - eliminating the transparent part in the picture

Comment: @Mazhar,I confirm that I have solved your problem. I have combined your original code with mine (your original code is at the bottom). If you successfully solve your problem, you can give me support. Thank you

Comment: @yangjiang, thank you for answering. Yes it did solve my problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can save the images as they are, without any frame or padding added:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread('matches.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
kernel = np.ones((4, 4), np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(img1, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)
fig.set_size_inches(10, 4)
ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])
ax.set_axis_off()
fig.add_axes(ax)

ax.imshow(img1, cmap='gray', aspect='auto')
fig.savefig("original.png")

ax.imshow(opening, cmap='gray', aspect='auto')
fig.savefig("opening of original.png")
```

Input image:

[image]

Output Images:

[image]

[image]

---

Of course, if you don't need to use `matplotlib` you can simply use the [`cv2.imwrite()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce) to write the images *(and [`cv2.show()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563) to show the images)*:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('matches.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
kernel = np.ones((4,4),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(img1, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

cv2.imwrite("original.png", img1)
cv2.imwrite("opening of original.png", opening)
```